# Georeferencing in QGIS: retrieve previously georeferenced tiff and points used

Tags: georeferencing, qgis-3

I having a problem going back to a tiff I georeferenced myself then closed to improve the georeference work.

I did it manually by adding points on the map and linking them to an already georeferenced vector. Now, when I first open my tiff (name.tif) in the georeferencer then upload the point file (name.points), the tiff and the points do not match together in the georeferencer while it works perfectly fine on my vector with all the points fitting at the right place in the QGIS window.

Comment: can you include a screenshot to illustrate the issue?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got the hang of it: I had  simply save my layer as a geotiff. Thanks for trying to help!

I am using QGIS 3.0 on mac. 
To save as a geotiff in the QGIS window: right click on your georeferenced raster layer > save as > enter the information and the file format you wish to save your layer (in that case, a geotiff). I also save the points in the georeferencer window by creating a .points file.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve this yourself.  Would you please **[edit]** your answer to include some steps you had to follow to save your layer as geotiff?  That way if someone in the future has the same problem your answer could be the solution for them.